# Whitespace on right side of website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a large amount of excess whitespace on the right hand side of my page (shown best when viewed on a mobile).

I believe this is caused by a margin-right somewhere but I can't seem to find the underlying issue.

**Live link:** http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two issues:

First, the #weeklyearningschartimage image should have a width of 100% so that it resizes with the parent.  This should fix most of the extra white space on mobile.

After fixing that, you may notice that there is still a small bit of white space on the right side (even on desktop).  This is because the .row elements are not wrapped in a .container-fluid

Check here for the proper grid HTML structure: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks will take a look, this is the first website I've built from scratch so I may be a little ropey!

Comment: You can also use the bootstrap class .img-responsive
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: Thanks, I've put all my rows in div's with a row class and put those into container-fluid classed divs this seems to have stopped the whitespace from showing but the content is no longer fluid to the right off the page, it's slightly cut off?

Comment: Huba huba! I've just seen that responsive image class!

Comment: Hmm, it looks like there are nested `.row` in the Latest blog posts area.

If you want to nest grid elements make sure they follow the structure:

    container (root element only)
        row
            column
                row
                    column

So only one container and groups of nested row > columns

Comment: container (root element) > (row > column (row > column) )

So only one container and groups of nested row > columns
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0):

I imagine part of the problem is...

```
<div class="row richard">

.richard {
    background-color: #232323;
    color: white;
    font-size: 130%;
    padding: 2%; <-------- This applies to left and right as well
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You are adding padding to the left and right of a row which might give you overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  I see what's wrong in your website, see your code

```
<div class="row light-section">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 homepage-text">
```

the class `homepage-text` you have written `max-with: 700px;` please fix it with some %(80-90).